ROS using Docker and VNC
I am new to ROS1 and I would like to use it without installing anything except Docker. I have a MAC with M3 (no XQuartz installed).
I have managed create a docker compose file using 2 images: theasp/novnc and osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full.
My docker-compose file looks like this:
version: '2'

services:
  ros:
    build: .
    container_name: ros_container
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=novnc:0.0
    depends_on:
      - novnc
    volumes:
      - ./catkin_ws:/root/catkin_ws
    command: bash -c "/root/init_workspace.sh && exec bash"
    networks:
      - x11
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  novnc:
    image: theasp/novnc:latest
    container_name: vnc_container
    environment:
      - DISPLAY_WIDTH=1600
      - DISPLAY_HEIGHT=968
      - RUN_XTERM=no
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - x11

networks:
  x11:

I basically used the example from here.
I saw that this image doesn't support setting up a password (see here) and when I go to http://localhost:8080/vnc.html I can just connect without any credentials. I am using a secure network. In this localhost I can to open rqt graph.
I have seen the rocker project, but when I install rocker using pip and run rocker --x11 osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full I still get the error /bin/sh: xauth: command not found. My guess is because I am using Quartz as my native graphics rendering layer.
So my question is:
Is this secure? Is there a better way to do the same?

Security Concerns

VNC Authentication: By default, the theasp/novnc image does not support setting up a password. This means anyone on the same network can access your VNC server if they know the address. If your network is secure and you trust all devices on it, this might be acceptable, but it's not ideal. You can look into other VNC server Docker images that support password authentication or modify the existing image to include it.

Network Isolation: Ensure your Docker network is isolated and restrict access to only the necessary services. Consider setting up firewall rules to limit access to the VNC server.

NoVNC Updates: Regularly update your Docker images to ensure you have the latest security patches.


Improvements

Using Rocker for X11: The xauth: command not found error suggests that xauth is not installed in your container. You can create a custom Dockerfile that installs xauth.
FROM osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xauth

Build this Dockerfile and use it with Rocker:
docker build -t my_ros_image .
rocker --x11 my_ros_image


Docker-Compose with Password-protected VNC: You can modify the theasp/novnc image or use an alternative that supports VNC passwords. Here's an example of modifying your existing setup:
version: '2'

services:
  ros:
    build: .
    container_name: ros_container
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=novnc:0.0
    depends_on:
      - novnc
    volumes:
      - ./catkin_ws:/root/catkin_ws
    command: bash -c "/root/init_workspace.sh && exec bash"
    networks:
      - x11
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  novnc:
    image: theasp/novnc:latest
    container_name: vnc_container
    environment:
      - DISPLAY_WIDTH=1600
      - DISPLAY_HEIGHT=968
      - RUN_XTERM=no
      - VNC_PASSWORD=my_secure_password # Add password here
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - x11

networks:
  x11:

Note: Ensure the VNC_PASSWORD environment variable is supported by the theasp/novnc image or find an alternative image that supports it.

Using Docker Secrets: For sensitive information like passwords, consider using Docker secrets instead of plain environment variables.



I have successfully used novnc with docker and put it together as a rocker extension.
https://github.com/tfoote/novnc-rocker
It hasn't been used in a few years, but it shouldn't be too hard to bring forward to modern usage. Contributions for that purpose would be appreciated.
Re the availability of auth, that is definitely related to your local system. Are you running x11 or Wayland? If the later x11 forwarding might not be what you want or need.

I have Quartz for core graphics. I have a MAC and I have not installed XQuartz - therefore I don't have X11. Ideally I would like to find a way where I don't need to install XQuartz.
